# Adding the elements of a list

Tags: python, string, list, dictionary, int

I am trying to add all the elements of a list and find its average.

```
[[0.7,5,6,4,2,45,7,8,5,3,2,6,8,3,2,2,5,4]]
```

And my code to find the average is:

```
avg = sum(lst)/len(lst)
```

Error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'

I think it's causing that because it is a list of list, but i do not want to change my output of the list since this output took me almost 100 lines of coding to do.
How can i add all these elements without damaging my code?
LNG - PYTHON

Answer (score 2):

It should be `avg = sum(lst[0])/len(lst[0])`

Answer (score 2):

Try using pop:

```
list = [[1,2,3,4,5]]

innerList = list.pop()

avg = sum( innerList ) / len ( innerList )

print avg
```

Result:

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can done this with numpy.

```
In [1]: import numpy as np
In [2]: lst = [[0.7,5,6,4,2,45,7,8,5,3,2,6,8,3,2,2,5,4]]
In [3]: np.mean(lst[0])
Out[3]: 6.5388888888888888
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I'd suggest you importing `division` if you want to make division the same behaviour in python2.x and 3.x.

```
>>> from __future__ import division
```

And you guess the reason is the nested list, and yes, that's the reason.So, the solution is easy, we use the inner list:

```
>>> lst = [[0.7,5,6,4,2,45,7,8,5,3,2,6,8,3,2,2,5,4]]
>>> average = sum(lst[0]) / len(lst[0])
>>> average 
6.538888888888889
```

If you're using python 3.4 or up, the std lib has the battery: [statistics.mean](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/statistics.html#statistics.mean)

```
>>> from statistics import mean
>>> mean(lst[0])
6.538888888888889
```